# White Half Sphere iMac G4 with Nvidia card

Tags: drivers, xorg, mac

There are more links about a G4 powerpc and a Nvidia card, but that information doesn't solve my problem.

I have a problem with installing Ubuntu on a old White Half Sphere iMac G4. The problem (for now) is the Nvidia card  [GeForce2 MX/MX 400]. Here a overview of mine actions.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-125-powerpc-smp ppc with option lubuntu minimum. Boot gives a dark rare screen.
So booting with yaboot: I use "Linux nomodeset single" to get the prompt.
I use openshh for the connection with the powerpc G4.

I've read that the problem is the driver nouveau and I had to replace driver nouveau with the old driver nv, I think.

To install nvidia GeForce driver I've used:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

In `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` I have changed in Section Device Driver "nouveau" in Driver "nv"

After booting and `startx` still I still have no Lubuntu.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are no proprietary drivers for such old cards that can still be used in modern distros.

Comment: On devtalk.nvidia.com they found the old driver.   https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=X.Org-1.19-Old-Driver-Updates   I have troubles to install that driver. I will go to ubuntuforms for help. Regards, Lucas

Comment: No, they didn't. Nothing to do with it.

Comment: I used https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2017-January/058569.html